# CasperJS' start is not working when there should have been a redirect

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

```
url = "https://example.com/";
casper.start(url, function () {
    this.echo('url: ' + url); 

    this.echo('myCloud requested...');
    this.echo('Page title: ' + this.getTitle());


});
casper.then(function () {
    this.echo('Clicking submit button...');

    this.click('input#SubmitButton');
...
```

When I request portalUrl ("https://example.com/") in a normal browser it redirects to ADFS Login page "ADFSloginUrl", but using CasperJS it cannot access login page of ADFS.

In above code **requested page not loaded**. So 'this.getTitle()' is empty and **cannot access submit button from CasperJS**.

When accessing submit button it gives following error:

> "Message: CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: input#SubmitButton"

Does this have anything to do with `casper.start`?

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Also which version of PhantomJS and CasperJS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**--ssl-protocol=any** has solved the problem for me.
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any yourcode.js

Thanks for all your answers and they were really helpful

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `waitFor`:

```
url = "https://example.com/";
casper.start(url, function () {
    this.echo('url: ' + url); 
});

casper.waitFor('input#SubmitButton', function () {
    this.echo('Page title: ' + this.getTitle());
    this.echo('Clicking submit button...');
    this.click('input#SubmitButton');
    }, function onTimeout(){
    this.echo("The submit button did not appear within 15 seconds...");
    }, 15000 ); //15 second timeout
```

If this does work it could indicate that the redirect is happening at the JavaScript, rather than the HTTP, level. (It is a good approach anyway, as otherwise subtle timing bugs can creep into your code.)

---

Alternatively, take a look at [this bug report](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/442) which points out that the behaviour is a bit different between PhantomJS and SlimerJS.